# Is there a way to detect when an element becomes invisible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any reliable way to detect when an element becomes invisible **from the users point of view**? So it should not only check stuff like *display:none* or *visibility:hidden* but also e.g. detect when another element with higher z-index is placed on top of the element.

(I don't think so but I'm asking anyway, in case I'm wrong.)

Edit: OK, question was closed, "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only". I'm not sure how to express myself better, to detect when an element becomes invisible from the users point of view seems like one single problem to me. Here is some code for the example I gave above, hope that makes the question clearer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn0").click(function(){
        $("#div0").css({"visibility":"visible"});
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id = "btn0">Click to hide this button with something</button> 
<div id="div0" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:10;background-color:green;visibility:hidden">Now you can't see the button</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, the user clicks the button and the div pops up. The button is still there behind the div element. It's "visibility" or "display" values has not changed. But to the user it is invisible. So what I'm after is some sort of reliable "elementUserVisibilityChanged" event for the button that I can subscribe to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]. It is good to provide any attempted code snippets.

Answer (score -2):

The **Intersection Observer** API is meant to do just that...

*“The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport.”*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

It can get pretty complex depending on your needs so happy reading!

Comment: Can you show (provide code) how to use this to do what OP has asked - eg when `$("#mydiv").hide()` is used?

Comment: Your "answer" is essentially just "intersection observer" with a link and definition, but no actual solution spelled out.